# ADSL Modulation Setting for better speed

Tags: networking, bandwidth, adsl2+

At home, I am still stuck with ADSL broadband connection. Recently I upgraded to 8mbps plan, and purchased a new DLink ADSL modem, and set it up. It's working fine, but the connection speed seems to be limited to 5.* mbps and won't go up. SNR and other common settings seem to be very good. I've tried several adsl modes and still couldn't get the 8mbps speeds. Has any one face this problem?

Comment: Using the original ADSL version (G.dmt), 8Mbps is the theoretical limit. You can only get that speed if you live right next to the exchange using very good copper wires. In realistic conditions, you'll never be able to reach that speed. You can only achieve better speed with later versions (ADSL2, 2+, etc.), but your ISP has to support it and you have to live within 3km to the exchange.

Comment: Ahh! I just cross 3km. Now then, I shall call them and demand my speed :)